# R - Line Chart axis overlap

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw a plot (I have no idea how this one could be called) and I have trouble with `axis` labels overlapping.

[image]

I was wondering if you have any advices to add some spaces between labels. 
Thanks.

Because the 3rd value is higher than the others I gave it a value of 30 and then labelled it with the real value 115.

```
dta$freqOri = dta$freq
dta$freq[3] <- 30
```

The plot loops

```
par(mar = c(0, 10.1, 0, 10.1)) 

for(i in 1:nrow(dta)){
  plot(0, ylim = c( min(dta$freq) - 5, max(dta$freq) + 2), bty = 'n', type = 'n', axes = F, ylab = '',  xlab = '')
  abline(h = dta$freq[i])
  axis(2, at = dta$freq[i], labels = dta$freqOri[i], las=2, tick = F, line = 7, cex.axis=0.6)
  axis(2, at = dta$freq[i], labels = dta$nameFrom[i], las=2, line = 0.5, tick =  F, cex.axis=0.6)
  axis(4, at = dta$freq[i], labels = dta$nameTo[i], las=2, line = 0.5, tick = F, cex.axis=0.6)
  par(new = T)
}
```

The data

```
dta = structure(list(freq = structure(c(8.5, 9, 30, 3.2, 13.4, 1.3, 
0.3, 4.1, 5.3, 6.7, 18.3, 5, 17.7, 2.1, 0.2, 4.5, 5.6, 8.5, 18.3
 ), .Dim = 19L, .Dimnames = structure(list(aaaa = c("a alone->b partner", 
"b partner->a alone", "b partner->b partner", "b partner->c child", 
"b partner->d nuclear", "b partner->e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"b partner->f children and acquaintance", "b partner->g partner and acquaintance", 
"b partner->h acquaintance", "b partner->i True Missing", "b partner->j work study sleep", 
 "c child->b partner", "d nuclear->b partner", "e nuclear and acquaintance->b partner", 
"f children and acquaintance->b partner", "g partner and acquaintance->b partner", 
"h acquaintance->b partner", "i True Missing->b partner", "j work study sleep->b partner"
)), .Names = "aaaa")), name = c("a alone->b partner", "b partner->a alone", 
"b partner->b partner", "b partner->c child", "b partner->d nuclear", 
"b partner->e nuclear and acquaintance", "b partner->f children and acquaintance", 
"b partner->g partner and acquaintance", "b partner->h acquaintance", 
"b partner->i True Missing", "b partner->j work study sleep", 
"c child->b partner", "d nuclear->b partner", "e nuclear and acquaintance->b partner", 
"f children and acquaintance->b partner", "g partner and acquaintance->b partner", 
 "h acquaintance->b partner", "i True Missing->b partner", "j work study sleep->b partner"
 ), nameFrom = c("a alone", "b partner", "b partner", "b partner", 
"b partner", "b partner", "b partner", "b partner", "b partner", 
"b partner", "b partner", "c child", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"f children and acquaintance", "g partner and acquaintance", 
"h acquaintance", "i True Missing", "j work study sleep"), nameTo = c("b partner", 
"a alone", "b partner", "c child", "d nuclear", "e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"f children and acquaintance", "g partner and acquaintance", 
"h acquaintance", "i True Missing", "j work study sleep", "b partner", 
"b partner", "b partner", "b partner", "b partner", "b partner", 
"b partner", "b partner"), freqOri = structure(c(8.5, 9, 115.2, 
 3.2, 13.4, 1.3, 0.3, 4.1, 5.3, 6.7, 18.3, 5, 17.7, 2.1, 0.2, 
 4.5, 5.6, 8.5, 18.3), .Dim = 19L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
aaaa = c("a alone->b partner", "b partner->a alone", "b partner->b partner", 
"b partner->c child", "b partner->d nuclear", "b partner->e nuclear and acquaintance", 
"b partner->f children and acquaintance", "b partner->g partner and acquaintance", 
"b partner->h acquaintance", "b partner->i True Missing", 
"b partner->j work study sleep", "c child->b partner", "d nuclear->b partner", 
"e nuclear and acquaintance->b partner", "f children and acquaintance->b partner", 
"g partner and acquaintance->b partner", "h acquaintance->b partner", 
"i True Missing->b partner", "j work study sleep->b partner"
)), .Names = "aaaa"))), .Names = c("freq", "name", "nameFrom", 
"nameTo", "freqOri"), row.names = c(NA, 19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried using log(dta$freq) as your y-variable?

Comment: Its actually a good idea. It works quite well if it first order the data and then attribute sequence number `1:nrow(dta)` and then log. We loose the proportions but it visually displays the info I want to share. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the overlapping has two separate causes: lines plotted at the same location and lines plotted close together. When the lines are plotted at the same location (e.g. 18.3 or 8.5) you could manually specify a rotation using the `srt` parameter in `text()` so that both labels are visible and terminate at the same location. You might need to change the `adj` parameter to control text justification as well.

When the lines are separate but the labels overlap, there are a few possibilities. First, the text size could be adjusted until the labels do not overlap, but they may not be readable. Second, the labels could be plotted horizontally off-set (not all justified to the same x location), which might entail extending some of the lines so that they terminate at the label. Thirdly, it might be possible to use the rotation method described above to separate these labels. Lastly, the lines could be plotted farther apart but labeled in the original units.